# dpkg: error processing package - Unable to repair/remove linux image version using apt and dpkg

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

**dpkg: error processing package - Unable to repair/remove linux image version using apt and dpkg**

---

I'm having an issue with `apt` and `dpkg` updating my linux kernel version.

Help would be greatly appreciated and I'm also looking at this as a good linux learning opportunity for myself :)

I've looked at many similar solutions online which suggest commands which when run end up in the same or very similar errors to what I've shown below or that I might have a full `/boot` dir but I don't believe this is the issue as it's reporting 50%. I'm unable to remove kernel versions to free up space anyway (see below errors):

The state I would like to get in would be to have the most up to date kernel version and have a couple of previous versions as fallbacks.

Currently `$ dpkg --list 'linux-image-*'` returns 50 or so versions (variations of `5.4*`, `5.8*` and `5.11*`)

```
$ sudo du -sh /boot
337M    /boot
$ sudo df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2    721392 328124    340804  50% /boot
```

My current kernel version is:

```
$ uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic
```

OS:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux thomas-labtop 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I'm getting:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 10.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 238716 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic (5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-84-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd: line 5: /usr/share/grub: Is a directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 126
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried purging the image using dpkg and I have also tried setting it to install:

```
$ echo "linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Subsequent `apt` commands end up setting it back to removed anyways.

I have been trying various `remove`, `purge` and `install` commands. Since `linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic` is in a `half-installed` state I figured I could either completely remove it so I can install it fresh or finish the current installation but have been unable to successfully prevent it being marked as removed.

The current state of `dpkg --list 'linux-image*'` is

```
$ dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                   Version               Architecture Description
+++-======================================-=====================-============-=================================
un  linux-image                            <none>                <none>       (no description available)
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic          5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic          5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rH  linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic          5.11.0-34.36~20.04.1  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
un  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-74-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
un  linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic           <none>                <none>       (no description available)
...
...
...
more below
```

Based on the lines:

```
/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd: line 5: /usr/share/grub: Is a directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 126
```

I looked into how to resolve this. Solutions online have suggested removing certain grub packages and reinstalling them. Given my current issues with `apt` I've refrained from doing this in case it makes the state of my machine even worse. Also I'm unable to run any state changing `apt` commands anyways.

---

Below is the content of `/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd`:

````
$ cat /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd
#! /bin/bash
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e

${pkgdatadir:?}
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"

if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      source /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?}
      prepare_grub_to_access_device '`${grub_probe} --target=device \${ESP}` | sed -e "s/^/\t/"'
cat << EOF
    chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi```
````

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; my guess is you're using a LTS release and have *opted* (*intentionally or unintentionally*) to the HWE stack which upgrades during the first two years of the  life cycle. Use the GA stack if you don't want this behavior.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   Note:  *I may have missed your real question; title detail needs to be repeated as some browser setups do not show title when viewing the page and your question is unclear I feel*

Comment: Hi. Thanks I will update with more specific OS information. As for the title I agree it's a bit vague but reflects me not having a good idea of the underlying issue.

Comment: Could you suggest a command I run to print the right information? In the meantime I've provided the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Probably GRUB configuration is messed up. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd`.

Comment: Will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update first. Go through all the cycles first.

```
reboot

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

And then so...

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update

reboot
```

Comment: Currently i can’t update as running apt update prompts me to run apt —fix-broken which yields the error above

Comment: Today I updated my Ubuntu 20.04.2 to version 20.04.3 and got a black screen, under which I hear the sound of volume up sliders. My EFI partition is banned in the disk management application. Later, I did a clean install of Ubuntu and again I was left on a black screen, under which I hear the sound of Ubuntu starting. Now I can run version 20.04.3 only in recovery mode via grub/advanced/recovery mode. In the boot/grub / section there is a file with commands to run in recovery mode and normal mode, see how they differ.

Comment: Try to do everything that you did, in recovery mode.

Comment: HI. I tried everything in recovery mode but getting pretty much the same error. Recovery also said that my machine is in "an unstable state".

Comment: Hi, try to run the `reinstall` command on all suspicious corners. At least, you can see what is happening on the screen of your monitor, I have it black as night )

Comment: Your suggestion isn't clear and your submitted answer won't work as explained in my question that I cannot install or upgrade anything currently until I have resolved the issue.

It sounds like you are having your own issue which I would suggest posting a new question about.

Comment: Like this: ```for p in `dpkg -l|egrep '^ii'|awk '{print $2}'`; do apt-get install --reinstall $p ; done```... Here for a separate package `apt-get install --reinstall ` where will the package name be. Yes, thank you, I already asked a question.

Comment: By the way, you can change the grub settings to delete or select a different kernel... `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`. You need to comment...`#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIE` and `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` so send: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: Look for information about this, unfortunately I can't check it yet.

Comment: It seems to me that I am also here will answer my own question )